# What was the name for a group of 12 men in old England responsible for each others actions?

Tags: england

I remember learning in school about how men in England were grouped together in a group of 12 or so and were responsible for eachothers actions (breaking law, debt, etc). What was the name of this practice?

Comment: er, what or when is "old England"?

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible that you're referring to the [Frankpledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankpledge)?

That wasn't a group of 12 men, but it was a group of men over the age of 12. Their households were collectively responsible for one another's conduct.

For completeness, both @RazieMah & @andy256 point out that the term  you're seeking may be [tithing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tithing), which is a territorial unit (1/10th of a hundred) of people who swear the *frankpledge*.  Credit to them, but I'm updating the answer so that it is a better reference.

Comment: I suspect that blarg is looking for *tithing*. I would post my own answer, but it's just one step from yours :-)

Comment: Yes, I agree with @andy256 The answer is tithing.